# How do I update 1 field in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I want a function to alter one field, "is_featured" to 1(true) of Event model of given ID, to mark an event as "Featured".

```
class EventsController extends AppController{
function feature($id){}
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

you can use saveField to do this
for example

```
$this->Event->id = $id;
$this->Event->saveField('is_featured', true);
```

Comment: Does the saveField function belong in the controller or model class?

Comment: @user2128444 Its a model function, but you can use it in both your controller and model. The example in the answer would be placed in the controller. Using it in the model would look like this `$this->id = $id; $this->saveField('is_featured', true);`.

Comment: Hello, I want to know is when table have no id field and how to save ? it not id use pid in my table. **$this->Event->pid=$id** is not ok? how to check my condition..

Comment: This method is being removed in 3.x. To be on the safe side and in light of as less upgrading issues as possible, you should not be using this anymore. Use save() instead. Or use Shim plugin + saveFieldbyId().

Answer (score 12):

You can perform update in one field by two ways:

```
    $this->Model->id=$id;
    $this->Model->saveField("fieldName","value");
```

OR

```
    $this->Model->updateAll(array("fieldName"=>"value"),array("fieldName"=>"condition"));
```

in second example, first array will update the value in defined field and second array defines the "WHERE" condition

Comment: -1 There are more than 2 ways to save a field. The two most obvious are [saveField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savefield-string-fieldname-string-fieldvalue-validate-false), and [save](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array).  updateAll is not a good idea if it's not necessary, and as written will produce an sql error as [fields are treated as sql expressions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions).

Comment: If we have `hasMany` or `belongsTo` relation in `Model` then first we will have to `unbind` unneccessary Models by `unbindModel` otherwise updateAll will not work. `$this->User->unbindModel(
            array('belongsTo' => array('Category', 'BodyHeight'))
        );`

Answer (score 12):

You can also use set() method

```
$this->Model->read(null, $id);
$this->Model->set(array(
      'fieldname' => 'value',
));
$this->Model->save();
```

Answer (score 4):

In cakephp 3 to update your data:

1. Include in your Controller:

   `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;`
2. In your action:

   ```
   $articlesTable = TableRegistry::get('Articles');
   $article = $articlesTable->get(12); // Return article with id 12

   $article->title = 'CakePHP is THE best PHP framework!';
   $articlesTable->save($article);
   ```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use this technique to update the field(s)

```
$this->Event->save($this->request->data, true, array('id', 'is_featured'))
```

If you don’t want the modified field to be automatically updated when saving some data add `'modified' => false` to your $data array
If you don’t pass the id, the model cannot set its primary key and will “add” instead of “edit” the field(s)

Comment: In my opinion, this is the safest method when you need to update more than one field. If only one field is to be updated, I would use `saveField`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easy way

```
$this->Event->saveField('username', $user); //Where username is Model field name and $user is value
```

Answer (score -3):

strangely; sometimes I like to resort for plain old sql: one-liner + no overhead there, makes me sure no callbacks/events get involved (beware this may be not what you want!)

```
$id = (int) $id;
$this->Event->query("UPDATE events SET is_featured=1 WHERE id=$id");
```